# String block formatting challenge

Tags: python, string, shell, formatting, awk

I'm working on a way to automatically download earthquake parameters from the National Earthquake Information Center (the USGS).  Unfortunately their format is a pile of crap, and I don't think I'll have much luck convincing them to change their format.  So, I have to format their `<pre>` block of html just to put it in tabular form.

But my experience with string formatting is limited, so I'm stuck (but sure there's someone out there who might have a solution).  Here's an example:

```
curl --silent http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqinthenews/2010/uu00002715/uu00002715_gcmt.php |\
sed -n '/<pre>/,/<\/pre>/p' |\
egrep -v '(#)|(pre>)' |\
egrep '(MW)|(ORIGIN)|(LAT)|(DEP)|(BEST DBLE)|(NP1)'
```

which gives the information I need formatted:

```
April 15, 2010, UTAH, MW=4.6
ORIGIN TIME:      23:59:42.8 0.4
LAT:41.72N 0.03;LON:110.86W 0.03
DEP: 12.5  1.8;TRIANG HDUR:  0.6
BEST DBLE.COUPLE:M0= 1.07*10**23
NP1: STRIKE=193;DIP=35;SLIP= -80
```

I would like a format such as this:

```
name date       time       lon     lat   dep  dep_err Mw  M0      strike dip slip
UTAH 2010/04/15 23:59:42.8 -110.86 41.72 12.5 1.8     4.6 1.07e23 193    35  -80
```

*Note the longitude is to be converted to east-longitude (hence the sign change).*

I'd like the solution to be in `awk`, `python`, or `unix shell` commands, but I'd entertain `ruby` or `perl` (I just probably won't understand what's going on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awk script that gets you most of the way there. Transforming the Lon, date, M0, etc is left as an exercise:

```
curl --silent http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqinthenews/2010/uu00002715/uu00002715_gcmt.php |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = "[,:;= ]+"
        OFS = "^"
    }
    /<pre>/ {process=1}
    /<\/pre>/ {process=0}
    ! process {next}
    /MW=/ {
        date = $1 " " $2 " " $3
        place = $4
        mw = $NF
    }
    /^ORIGIN TIME:/ {
        otime = $3 ":" $4 ":" $5
    }
    /^LAT:.*LON:/ {
        lat = $2
        lon = $5
    }
    /^DEP:/ {
        dep = $2
        dep_err = $3
    }
    /^BEST DBLE.COUPLE:/ {
        m0 = $NF
    }
    /^NP1:/ {
        strike = $3
        dip = $5
        slip = $7
    }
    END {
        print "name", "date", "time", "lon", "lat", "dep", "dep_err", "Mw", "M0", "strike", "dip", "slip"
        print place, date, otime, lon, lat, dep, dep_err, mw, m0, strike, dip, slip
    }
' | column -s ^ -t
```

Output:

```
name  date           time        lon      lat     dep   dep_err  Mw   M0           strike  dip  slip
UTAH  April 15 2010  23:59:42.8  110.86W  41.72N  12.5  1.8      4.6  1.07*10**23  193     35   -80
```

Comment: I am humbled.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use one of their XML formatted feeds such as [this one](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/7day-M2.5.xml). I'm sure it's easier to parse.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion.  The issue is scientific: I need to make sure the solution they publish (and I'm using) is a final estimate - not an initial estimate.  In many cases their published model takes hours to days to refine, so I can't depend on an immediate RSS feed.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing html with regular expressions is normally seen as a very, very bad idea, so I'd second Abizern's suggestion of using the RSS feed. In fact, the USGS provide XML downloads also (see http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/).

If for some reason you can't do that and *have* to use the html, then as the `<pre>` block has no further structure (ruling out something nice like using lxml or beautifulsoup) then the following python works for this *single* example...the regular expression is probably very fragile (and frankly, cludgey) and would need tweaking to handle further examples/exceptions.

This writes out to an excel file, so you should be able to pop it all in a loop to scrape multiple pages (play nice and check their terms, restrict the rate and cache).

```
import httplib2
import re
from xlwt import Workbook

h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
url = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eqinthenews/2010/uu00002715/uu00002715_gcmt.php'
resp, content = h.request(url, "GET")
regex = re.compile("<pre>\s*(?P<date>.* \d{2}, \d{4}), (?P<name>\w.*), MW=(?P<Mw>\d.\d).*ORIGIN TIME:\s*(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d).*LAT:\s*(?P<lat>\d{2,3}.\d{2,3}[N|S]).*LON:\s*(?P<lon>\d{2,3}.\d{2,3}[W|E]).*DEP:\s*(?P<dep>\d{2,3}.\d)\s*(?P<dep_err>\d{1,3}.\d);.*M0=\s*(?P<M0>\d.\d{1,2}\*\d{1,2}\*\*\d{1,2}).*STRIKE=(?P<strike>\d{1,3}).*DIP=(?P<dip>\d{1,3}).*SLIP=\s*(?P<slip>[-|+]\d{1,3}).*NP2",re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
r = regex.search(content)
data = r.groupdict()

headers = ['name', 'date', 'time', 'lon', 'lat', 'dep', 'dep_err', 'Mw', 'M0', 'strike', 'dip', 'slip']
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Quakes')

column = 0
for header in headers:
    ws.write(0, column, header)
    ws.write(1, column,data[header])
    column+=1
wb.save('quakes.xls')
```

You should ***definitely*** use the XML/RSS instead though if you can :)

Comment: That's a very nice solution @craigs.  The problem is, yes, I _must_ use the html (see my response to @Abizern).